# How can I have a relationship between models based off an attributes value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I have the three following models...

**Player**

```
id:integer
first_name:string
last_name:string
```

**School**

```
id:integer
short_name:string
long_name:string
```

**SchoolRosterSlot**

```
id:integer
season:integer
jersey:string
position:string
active:boolean
```

Originally I was going to have jersey, position, school_id stored on the Player model.  However, I changed that because I thought it would be redundant to enter that information into the Player model, and also insert it in the SchoolRosterSlot model since I'm wanting to store season information on players. (the players postiion, jersey, and school can all change from season-to-season).

My question is how do I set up my associations so that I can access the player's school via `@player.school` for instance? or `@player.jersey`... or is it better to set up a direct association between school and player and just insert the roster slot record also even though this would be recording the information twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want to avoid storing duplicate information whenever possible.

You could try adding `school_roster_slot_id` to Player and `school_id` to SchoolRosterSlot, then adding this to the models:

```
class SchoolRosterSlot
  belongs_to :school
end

class Player
  belongs_to :school_roster_slot
  has_one :school, through: :school_roster:slot
end
```

This will create a `player.school` method. If you want to also get `player.jersey` and `player.position` you could also add this to Player:

```
delegate :position, :jersey, to :school_roster_slot
```

This is effectively the same as creating the following two methods:

```
def jersey
  school_roster_slot.jersey
end

def position
  school_roster_slot.position
end
```

I don't know if you want to store historical information about player's positions and jerseys (e.g. when a player changes position and jersey, do you still want to store information about their old positions?), but if that's the case you might need to do something like creating an additional model called `Season` that sits in between `Player` and `SchoolRosterSlot`. Or maybe you could add `start_date` and `end_date` to `SchoolRosterSlot` to denote when a player starts and leaves that slot?

Comment: thanks! I'm about to jump back into this and see if I can get this to work.  And yes I do want to store historical information such as a school, jersey, & position for each season. Which was the thing kinda throwing me off here. I was thinking perhaps of making a SchoolRosterHistorical which would have a record inserted when a new SchoolRosterSlot season was entered. But this method also seemed to have some potential issues.

Comment: is it possible to add a conditional statement to the `has_one :school` association?  So I would have some way of ordering the records for a player in desc order on season and then limit the query to 1 return. This way I would get the record with the most recent season?